# how to load data received from ajax in another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, apache-cordova

I have following pages

1. Page1.html
2. Page2.html
3. JavaScript.js

My first page makes ajax call on button click and receives response successfully..

I want to load that data in another page (Page2.html)..

```
$.ajax(
  .....
  .....
  .....
  success: function(response){
    window.location.href="Page2.html";
    $("#content").append(data);     
  }
);
```

My div with id of content is on another page(Page2.html)...
Note: All my script are in the js file..

How can I perform the above task?

Comment: There are 2 things which is creating problem.1) You are redirecting the page and then try to append content, it is not possible...2) You can not set content of page2.html from page1.html

Comment: any suggestion how to perform this

Comment: can you show the full ajax request?

Comment: My Html pages are dynamically generated

Comment: sry.. i cant show my ajax request.. But it is successfully retrieving data

Comment: I do not know your set up but curiously, why don't you setup the `ajax` call in page 2 itself. Do you have any special scenario you are doing it this way??

Comment: Yes bro.. In page 1 there are number of buttons which load different data..

Comment: My task is to show that data in list type in page2

Comment: My page2 is common page which generates dynamic list

Comment: So you can create popup windows no?

Comment: Or you can assign content to window before opening it

Comment: Anyway because you redirect page, I would not use Ajax. But would pass some data identification by link to Page2.html and display content depending on that param, for ex: `Page2.html?data-requested=button3`

Comment: My intention is not to create a popup.. I want to show that data in a specified page(Page 2)

Answer (score 0):

Solution I: With Jquery,

You need to include Jquery plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie:

```
$.cookie("data", data);
```

Solution II: Using Localstorage. [Supported in all modern browsers]

```
var data = 123;
// Put the var into storage
localStorage.setItem('data', data);

// Retrieve the var from storage
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem('data');

console.log(retrievedData);
```

Comment: Or alternatively you can use localStorage If you are supporting modern browsers only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browser local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which will persist your data on subsequent page visits with no expiration time. It has well support in browsers from IE-8 to all modern browsers so it will work without any hassle.

To store data in you need to access the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object and set data like this on `page1.html`.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    ...
    success: function (result) {
        localStorage.setItem('MyData', result);
    }
});
```

On `page2.html`, you can retrieve data from `localStorage` object using the same key (`MyData`) name we used to set data. You can choose any meaningful name for this.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('MyData');
console.log("use data wherever you want...", data);
```